# Unable to delete the update product from minicart through ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, mini-cart, form-key

I am unable to delete the updated product from the mini cart.
this is the code:
path : app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

```
public function ajaxUpdateAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            Mage::throwException('Invalid form key');
        }
        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        $result = array();
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $cart = $this->_getCart();
                if (isset($qty)) {
                    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                        array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                    );
                    $qty = $filter->filter($qty);
                }

                $quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
                if (!$quoteItem) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('Quote item is not found.'));
                }
                if ($qty == 0) {
                    $cart->removeItem($id);
                } else {
                    $quoteItem->setQty($qty)->save();
                }
                $this->_getCart()->save();

                $this->loadLayout();
                $result['content'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_content')->toHtml();

                $result['qty'] = $this->_getCart()->getSummaryQty();

                if (!$quoteItem->getHasError()) {
                    $result['message'] = $this->__('Item was updated successfully.');
                } else {
                    $result['notice'] = $quoteItem->getMessage();
                }
                $result['success'] = 1;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $result['success'] = 0;
                $result['error'] = $this->__('Can not save item.');
            }
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

Getting below error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Invalid form key

Trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(636): Mage::throwException('Invalid form ke...')
#1 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->ajaxUpdateAction()
#2 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('ajaxUpdate')
#3 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

What I am getting in the URL:
  http://example.com/checkout/cart/ajaxUpdate/id/11487/uenc/aHR0cDovL3dlYmRlbW8ubGV0c2NoYmFuZy5jby5pbi9yYXdwcmVzc2VyeS9hamF4Y2FydC9pbmRleC9hZGQvdWVuYy9hSFIwY0RvdkwzZGxZbVJsYlc4dWJHVjBjMk5vWW1GdVp5NWpieTVwYmk5eVlYZHdjbVZ6YzJWeWVTOWlkVzVrYkdWekxtaDBiV3csL3Byb2R1Y3QvODAvZm9ybV9rZXkvdkJkTUJtN3FBaHRsWDl3NS8,/

Can I know what was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your minicart form section -

```
 <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: where should i put this code  can i know the file path

Comment: there is no form for mini cart

Comment: is this default magento mini cart?

Comment: yes this is the default magento mini cart

Comment: from where I mean where you fire the ajax action to pass the parameter to controller action at there also pass this form key.